# Regex Example Confusion

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I am preparing for Oracle Certified Java Programmer. I am looking into regular expressions. I was going through javaranch [Regular Expression](http://www.coderanch.com/t/375438/java/java/appendReplacement-appendTail) and i am not able to understand the regular expression present in the example. Please help me in understanding it. I am adding source code for reference here. Thanks.

```
class Test
{
  static Map props = new HashMap();
  static
  {
    props.put("key1", "fox");
    props.put("key2", "dog");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "The quick brown ${key1} jumps over the lazy ${key2}.";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
    {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
      sb.append(props.get(m.group(1)));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you not understand in that code?

Comment: I am not able to disect the regular expression. First can you help me what does this regular expression interpret.

Comment: @benz: Look at this: [www.debuggex.com/r/g6_JM9gTX5RDSA5R](http://www.debuggex.com/r/g6_JM9gTX5RDSA5R)

Comment: It looks for things like `${key1}` and `${key2}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a very good tutorial on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) you might want to check out. [The article on quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) has two sections "Laziness instead of Greediness" and "An Alternative to Laziness", that should explain this particular example really well.

Anyway, here is my explanation. First, you need to realize that there are two compilation steps in Java. One compiles the string literal in your code to an actual string. This step already interprets some of the backslashes, so that the string Java receives looks like

```
\$\{([^}]+)\}
```

Now let's pick that apart in free-spacing mode:

```
\$      # match a literal $
\{      # match a literal {
(       # start capturing group 1
  [^}]  # match any single character except } - note the negation by ^
  +     # repeat one or more times
)       # end of capturing group 1
\}      # match a literal }
```

So this really matches all occurrences of `${...}`, where `...` can be anything except closing `}`. The contents of the braces (i.e. the `...`) can later be accessed via `m.group(1)`, as it's the first set of parentheses in the expression.

Here are some more relevant articles of the above tutorial (but you should really read it in its entirety - it's definite worth it):

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (including how to negate them with `^`)
- [Repetition/quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [Grouping and capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Java's regex peculiarities](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Comment: Thanks buettner. I will look into this tutorial in detail and get back to this example so that i can understand. Because i am currently confused many blogs say ^, it means start of line rather then negation.

Comment: @benz it does, if you use it outside of a character class. inside a character class that meaning doesn't make sense though, because "the beginning of the string/line" is not a character (but a position). so it can have a different meaning in character classes. if it's the first character, it negates the class. if it's at any other position inside a character classes, it's simply treated as a literal `^`.

Answer (score 3):

An illustration of your regex:

```
\$\{([^}]+)\}
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/7Y_7BmoBKWzr74tn)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

```
\\$         literal $ (must be escaped since it is a special character that 
            means "end of the string"
\\{         literal { (i m not sure this must be escaped but it doesn't matter)
(           open the capture group 1
  [^}]+     character class containing all chars but }
)           close the capture group 1
\\}         literal }
```

Answer (score 1):

- `\\$`: matches a literal dollar sign. Without the backslashes, it matches the end of a string.
- `\\{`: matches a literal opening curly brace.
- `(`: start of a capturing group

  - `[^}]`: matches any character that isn't a closing curly brace.
  - `+`: repeats the last character set, which will match one or more characters that aren't curly braces.
- `)`: closing capturing group.
- `\\}`: matches a literal closing curly brace.

It matches stuff that looks like `${key1}`.

Comment: Thanks Blender. I am confused at many places ^ and blogs it interprets to start of the line. Additionally what is the use of $ sign in this regex?

Comment: @benz: Do you know what this regex even does?

Comment: Blender to me it is trying to find all the occurances {}. I am sorry i am pretty new into regex stuff right now.

Comment: @benz Character classes have their own metacharacters - and some of them are the same as metacharacters outside of character classes, but they may have a different meaning.